# How I can make my Jquery script to run only when devices is a mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, web

I am thinking to build a JQuery mobile app for my domain. But I don't know How I can ensure it when domain is reached through computer or laptop then my regular site shows up. But when someone open up the site through Tablet or mobile phone then my JQuery app shows up?

That JQuery mobile app is totally a different script.

Can anyone tell me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use css to do this:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px){
    //what ever you want to hide
    body {
      display:none;
   }
}
```

And you must have meta tag to this work:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

Comment: This will hide entirely body when you view the side between 320 - 568px :)

Comment: Then How I can display mobile site?